# Where can I read hints again?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

While driving, the game gives us some hints about the game in upper left corner of the screen.

I'm not accustomed to the game yet. So, I need full concentration when I drive and I don't have time to read the hints. And English is my second language, I need a little bit more time :-)

Can I see the hints again somewhere ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/before-you-start-tips-for-playing-gta-v-1333219413):

> You can read all of the game's recent notifications in the pause menu. Just pause the game, select "Brief" and flip down to both "Help" and "Notifications." Note that the option to read recent dialogue truncates the script, so if you find yourself missing what people are saying, turn on subtitles.